# Need help on understanding generated JNI header file

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I was going through JNI tutorial and I came across below line in generated header file.

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_ReadFile_loadFile
(JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);
```

I can understand the meaning of *jbyteArray*, *JNIEnv*, *jobject* and *jstring*.These are required to pass information to and from c program. But I was not able to understand why are **JNIEXPORT** and **JNICALL** are used. And what are these termed as in c program(function, Structure, Enum - I regret if this question is very trivial)? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> JNIEXPORT and JNICALL are macros used
>   to specify the calling and linkage
>   convention of both JNI functions and
>   native method implementations.

See [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/types.html) section 12.4

For example, in my jvm (Ubuntu 32bit), the header file `jni_md.h` contains:

```
#define JNIEXPORT 
#define JNIIMPORT
#define JNICALL
```

Which will make your function look like:
jbyteArray Java_ReadFile_loadFile
    (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

While win32 jni_md.h contains:

```
#define JNIEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#define JNICALL __stdcall
```

Since windows use different calling conventions and your function will look like:

```
__declspec(dllexport) jbyteArray __stdcall Java_ReadFile_loadFile
(JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);
```